# How to debug asyncio coroutines in python in general

Tags: python, debugging, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm working on my project with asyncio coroutines and find it hard to get an error and debug the code, is there a general source/method that someone can point me to how to debug coroutines?

Comment: Have you tried the same methods you normally use to debug Python, such as `pdb` or the debugger in your IDE? Can you give an example of error that you find hard to get?

Answer (score 0):

```
asyncio.run(async_fn(), debug=True)
```

More details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-debug-mode

Also it's already in Pycharm 2022.3 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22961